# Slice on the queryset argument of a Django Prefetch object and got "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken."

Tags: python, django

I did a slice on the queryset argument of a Django Prefetch object and got "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken."

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

queryset = SomeModel.objects.filter(some_field=some_value).order_by('id')[:5]

prefetch_obj = Prefetch('related_field', queryset=queryset)

some_queryset.prefetch_related(prefetch_obj)
```

Is there any way to slice only the first 5 query sets to be cached by prefetch?

Comment: I don't think so. That would mean `some_object.related_field.all()` isn't `all`, but "last 5".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, because, you cannot know if the first five items of your prefetching queryset will correspond to the needed prefetch items for the `some_queryset`. I think you want to slice on the `some_queryset` instead of your prefetch queryset (this last one will be queried according to the limit option of the main queryset).

```py
queryset = SomeModel.objects.filter(some_field=some_value).order_by('id')

prefetch_obj = Prefetch('related_field', queryset=queryset)

results_queryset = some_queryset.prefetch_related(prefetch_obj)[:5]
```